# Do prediction without fitting the model (knn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When i comment the `knn.fit(x_tr,y_tr)` in below code and run, it gives an error `NotFittedError: This KNeighborsClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.`

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
print(knn)
# knn.fit(x_tr, y_tr)
# print(knn)
pred = knn.predict(x_cv)
acc = accuracy_score(y_cv, pred, normalize=True) * float(100)
```

my disconnect is that i havent saved `knn.fit(...)` in any variable, how does the program knows that i havent fitted ?

Also when i print the model after initiation and after fitting...it exactly is the same

```
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
                     metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
                     weights='uniform')
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
                     metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
                     weights='uniform')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look into the `KNeighborsClassifier` code, `knn` instance will store trained parameters/info in `self`. That's why the program knows.

For more details, when `knn.predict` is triggered.

- It first calls `neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)` in
  `sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py` (line #175)
- Next, it calls  `check_is_fitted(self)` in `sklearn\neighbors\_base.py` (line #585)